# what should I do about missing namespaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference

While using Visual Studio C# Express 2010, I've noticed a small problem; namespaces such as System.Windows and System.Drawing are missing, so where could I find them, or can I download them online?

P.S: I've opened the System reference and really got worried as I didn't find those references.

Comment: Make sure you do not have ".NET client profile" set as target framework

Comment: What does "opened the System reference" mean?  Go ahead and worry if you don't see them in Project + Add Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two assemblies you mentioned are available only for Windows applications. If you are creating a console application such assemblies are not even shown in the Add References.

Comment: thanks alot! I was using an empty project, thinking I can use anything wanted.

Comment: Davide Piras,
 As You've been so helpful for me since I've enrolled and never known somebody at this site, I'd love to tell you that :
 You are officially My Mentor ^_^

Answer (score 1):

1. Under your references folder, in the *Solution Explorer* click `Add Reference`
2. Click the .NET tab.
3. Find your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open up your Add Reference dialog you should have a .NET tab. In there you should find the references you require.

System.Windows may not be there but its members should be.